# Server Ubuntu 20.04 move file and folder to root

Tags: server, apache2

I have initialize a new repo on my ubuntu server and then made git clone for my repo, now I have my root folder server name and inside it I have another folder with my repo name.

```
-my-server-root-folder
--My-repo-name
```

I want to move all the file and folders to the `-my-server-root-folder`

I try this `mv  -v /var/www/my-server-root-folder/My-repo-name/ /var/www/my-server-root-folder/`

says `/var/www/my-server-root-folder/My-repo-name/` and `/var/www/my-server-root-folder/My-repo-name/` are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I have found another good way to this

```
mv * .[^.]* ..
```

This made the trick